# Making a for loop print with an index

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, format, string-formatting

I made a program which displays a user-provided number of the fibonacci series. I wanted to format it into an indexed list, but I don't what could I use to do so. I found the enumerate() function, but seems it only works for premade lists, whereas mine is generated accordingly to the user.

Do I use a for loop to generate a variable along with the series, then put the variable in the for loop that prints the numbers, like so:

```
print("{0}. {1}".format(index_variable, wee(n)))
```

or am I going down an entirely wrong road here?

Comment: Take the user input inside a generator, then pass the generator to `enumerate`. You could also just loop over a `range`, and ask for input inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fib(n):
    x = 0
    y = 1
    for i in range(n):
        yield y
        tmp = x
        x = y
        y += tmp

def main():
     n = input('How many do you want: ')
     for i, f in enumerate(fib(n)):
         print("{0}. {1}".format(i, f)
```

Make  a generator that yields the values you want and then pass that to `enumerate`